# Apache HttpClient how to - basic auth in request through authentication proxy

Tags: java, apache, authentication, proxy

What I would like is to create a http POST to a resource which requires me to use basic authentication. I would also like to make the request through a proxy which also requires me to authenticate.

So I found these examples:

https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientAuthentication.java

https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientProxyAuthentication.java

How do I combine them? How do I provide both username/pass for the basic auth and username/pass for the proxy?

Thanks!

Comment: Unless your proxy and your endpoint are on the same server, AuthScope should differentiate them

Comment: @nablex Okay, this is true. But do I need to supply two different AuthScopes or one AuthScope with multiple hosts? How do I do that?